# Transpose an address list to rows

Tags: google-sheets

I have a good old list with addresses:

[image]

Because I want to re-arrange the list (and make it more 2013), I need to transpose the list like this:

[image]

I've tried to use the `TRANSPOSE` formula, but that doesn't work.

Is there some other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the data has the same repetition as shown in your example, throughout the list, then the following formula would help you out:

```
=TRANSPOSE(INDIRECT("A"&(1+(5*(ROW(B1)-1))&":A"&(4+(5*(ROW(B1)-1))))))
```

Copy the formula downwards until it hits a ref#.

I've included a Google Spreadsheet file for you to take a look: [Transpose an Address List](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AluAYY6ZHeWYdDJKaVFodjhuX0c1eUUwMEpiaEVzX1E)

Good luck with your 2013-ish address list.